# how to make an ember-cli Ember 2 Ruby on Rails app

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Is there a summary of the changes or tutorial you need to do to get ember-cli to work with Ember 2? I did a project with Ember like 2 years ago and a potential client was interested in Ember 2. Or is there a new preferred way to build Ember / Rails apps?

Comment: ^^ I wish programmers actually knew what words like opinion-based mean lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ember-CLI with Ember 2.0 is not released yet. It's still on `1.13.8`. I assume they are waiting for all core components to be released under 2.0. E.g. `ember-data` released 2.0 just few days ago. So I would recommend you to wait for Ember-CLI 2.0 official release. After that you would have to just run `ember update`.

If you can't wait, you can change dependencies manually in `bower.json`.

Talking about Ember-CLI and Rails integration, please take a look at this project: https://github.com/rwz/ember-cli-rails

Comment: thx, I had looked at ember-cli-rails and, while interesting, the number of open issues seemed too high. Have you used it and had good experience?

Comment: I didn't use it in production, just experimented, but it worked fine for me. May be in some more complex projects there could be issues. For production I prefer to develop both UI and API as two independent apps and deploy them to different heroku instances.